# How to convert jquery attr value to a string object to use it as a regex expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, attr

i want to search a string variable if it contains a jQuery object's attr value. I have tryed this:

```
var txt = "lets go to a.html";
var searchText = new RegExp($("#link").attr("href"));
alert(txt.search(searchText)>=0);
```

but this always returns false.
im sure that $("#link").attr("href") returns "a.html" as value.
also i have tried this if i was doing something wrong,

```
var txt = "lets go to a.html";
var searchText = new RegExp("a.html");
alert(txt.search(searchText)>=0);
```

this time it has returned true.
i thought jquery was not returning a string object and i have tried to turn it to string like this:

```
var txt = "lets go to a.html";
var searchText = new String($("#link").attr("href"));
searchText = new RegExp(searchText);
alert(txt.search(searchText)>=0);
```

this has aslo returned false..

when i used toString($("#link").attr("href")) it always returns true even attr value is not "a.html"

anyone can help me on this?
thank you.

Comment: because regular expressions are not like search for text or string, they should be something like `/\s/` to find space and so on

Comment: Are you sure you want to use an URL as a regex? It seems weird.

Comment: you could use .indexOf to search a string

Comment: if the second example is works fine why it is not working when the text is coming from jquerys attr() function?

Comment: jQuery gets confused between properties and attributes (as does IE). Even though the attribute value is "a.html", using attr('href') may return the full path name, not the actual value. The attr method **is not** a pseudonym for get/setAttribute.

Comment: use `console.log()` and not `alert ()` you will save a lot of your time

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var txt = "lets go to a.html";
var searchText = $("#link").attr("href");
alert(txt.indexOf(searchText) !== -1);
```

Comment: It means that `searchText` does not equals to `"a.html"`.

Answer (score 1):

To create a regular expression from a string:

```
var re = new RegExp('your string');
```

To see if it matches another string:

```
re.test('another string');       // false
re.test('here is your string');  // true
```

Note though that some characters must be escaped, so to match a whitespace:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\s');
```

In your case, you should reverse the sense of the test:

```
searchText.test(txt)
```

which will return true if 'a.html' is in txt.

Comment: problem here is in this var re = new RegExp('your string');
its is not just like this this expression will work fine but when it like this: re = new RegExp($("#link").attr("href")); it is NOT working what is test() function by the way?

Comment: The test method returns true or false depending on whether a regular expression matches any part of a string. E.g /a/.test('cat') // true

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browser you are testing in the href attribute, when queried through jQuery, will return a fully qualified url even tho you have set it to a relative url.

Test to make sure that `$('#link').attr('href')` actually returns `a.html` and not `http://url/a.html`.

Comment: This depends on the jQuery version, but you are right, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay problem is solved i must say sorry to everyone who spent time to solve this problem
problem was on my html :(
i have putted an emty character inside the href attribute like this:

```
<a href="a.html ">
```

the codes i have given all are working well :)